# angular 2 formbuilder conditional validating input

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular 2 formbuilder to create a form and I want to conditionally validate the input field according to radio box input changes.when I click percentage radio box the percentage input should be validated. When I click amount radio box it should validate amount input field.

### HTML Code

(I am using material input components)

```
<md-radio-group formControlName="splitType" (click)="splitTypeClicked()">
      <md-radio-button value="amount">Amount</md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button value="percentage">Percentage</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
  
<input  mdInput  placeholder="Amount" formControlName="amount"  >
<input  mdInput   placeholder="Percentage" formControlName="percentage"  >
```

### Angular 2 Component

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
   
  ngOnInit() {

    this.splitChargeForm = this.fb.group({
      splitType: ['', Validators.required],
      amount: [''],        //validate when splitType = amount
      percentage: ['']     //validate when splitType = percentage

   });
```

Comment: you hide/show and disable/ enable input on click?

Comment: yes hide/show when clicking radio buttons

Comment: ok i  update my answer

Comment: you can try 2nd solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

write this code into `ngOnInit()` method. does this help

**Solution 1:**

```
 this.splitChargeForm.get('splitType')
      .valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
          if (value === 'amount') {       
               this.splitChargeForm.get('amount').setValidators(Validators.required);
               this.splitChargeForm.get('percentage').clearValidators()
          } else {
              this.splitChargeForm.get('percentage').setValidators(Validators.required);
              this.splitChargeForm.get('amount').clearValidators()
        }
    });
```

**Solution 2:**

// formBuilder

```
  this.splitChargeForm = this.fb.group({
      splitType: ['', Validators.required],
      amount: [{value: '', disabled: false}, Validators.required], 
      percentage: [{value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required]
   });
```

// enable & disable input (write in onInit() method or cunstructor)

```
this.splitChargeForm.get('splitType')
          .valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
              if (value === 'amount') {       
                   this.splitChargeForm.get('amount').enable;
                   this.splitChargeForm.get('percentage').disable();
              } else {
                  this.splitChargeForm.get('percentage').enable();
                  this.splitChargeForm.get('amount').disable()
            }
        });
```

Html should be like

```
<md-radio-group formControlName="splitType" (click)="splitTypeClicked()">
      <md-radio-button value="amount">Amount</md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button value="percentage">Percentage</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>

<input  mdInput  placeholder="Amount" formControlName="amount" *ngIf="splitChargeForm.value.splitType === 'amount" >
<input  mdInput   placeholder="Percentage" formControlName="percentage"  *ngIf="splitChargeForm.value.splitType === 'percentage" >
```

Comment: this is really comprehensive answer! thanks for your time.